# Warning: fsck not present, so skipping root file system

Tags: 18.04, crash

My server (18.04) crashes during startup. One of the messages that is shown and which I think may be the reason for it is:

```
Warning: fsck not present, so skipping root file system
[      5.502634] EXT4-fs (sda2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[      5.503676] EXT4-fs (sda2): write access will be enabled during recovery
[      5.544074] EXT4-fs (sda2): recovery complete
[      5.548989] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks,
Tom

Edit: Image added
[Ubuntu startup before crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCVQJ.jpg)

Comment: what results do you get when you do this: apt search e2fsprogs ? or - if you can never boot it up, can you attach the hd to another linux computer and run fsck on it?

Comment: Is the disk in that server ext4? The 5 or 6 lines before the 1st line you posted are important too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution described [here](https://forum.armbian.com/topic/11207-include-fsck-on-a-init-ramdisk-espressobin/?do=findComment&comment=84245) worked perfectly for me.

umiddelb wrote:

> You need to add the relevant executables:
>
> ```
> echo \
> '#!/bin/sh
> . /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions
> copy_exec /sbin/e2fsck /sbin
> copy_exec /sbin/fsck /sbin
> copy_exec /sbin/fsck.ext2 /sbin
> copy_exec /sbin/fsck.ext4 /sbin
> copy_exec /sbin/logsave /sbin' \
>   | sudo dd of=/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/e2fsck.sh
> sudo chmod +x /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/e2fsck.sh
> ```
>
> before building the initrd
>
> ```
> sudo update-initramfs -c -k ${kver}
> ```

After that, reboot and checkout the results.